# Помогите в реализации считание номеров слайдера

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу в слайдер добавить считывание номеров.

Логику взял  [отсуда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823571/how-to-get-total-and-current-slide-number-of-carousel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Но там на jQuery релизовано а мне нужно в js

Я заменил их код на `Javascript` и посмотрел что алтернатива `index() jQuery` в `JavaScript` это `indexOf()`

Но вот при добавлени этого кода

`var $currentIndex = document.querySelector('figure.bss-show').indexOf() + 1;`

в  слайдер показывает ошибку такого рода что **indexOf() is not a function**

Помогите как мне реализовать такой отчет слайдера `1 / 10`

```js
var makeBSS = function (el, options) {
    var $slideshows = document.querySelectorAll(el), // a collection of all of the slideshow
        $slideshow = {},
        Slideshow = {
            init: function (el, options) {
                this.counter = 0; // to keep track of current slide
                this.el = el; // current slideshow container    
                this.$items = el.querySelectorAll('figure'); // a collection of all of the slides, caching for performance
                this.numItems = this.$items.length; // total number of slides         
                options = options || {}; // if options object not passed in, then set to empty object 
                options.auto = options.auto || false; // if options.auto object not passed in, then set to false
                this.opts = {
                    auto: (typeof options.auto === "undefined") ? false : options.auto,
                    speed: (typeof options.auto.speed === "undefined") ? 1500 : options.auto.speed,
                    pauseOnHover: (typeof options.auto.pauseOnHover === "undefined") ? false : options.auto.pauseOnHover,
                    fullScreen: (typeof options.fullScreen === "undefined") ? false : options.fullScreen,
                    swipe: (typeof options.swipe === "undefined") ? false : options.swipe
                };
                
                this.$items[0].classList.add('bss-show'); // add show class to first figure 
         //   var $currentIndex = document.querySelector('figure.bss-show').indexOf() + 1; строка ошибки 
                this.injectControls(el);
                this.addEventListeners(el);
                if (this.opts.auto) {
                    this.autoCycle(this.el, this.opts.speed, this.opts.pauseOnHover);
                }
                if (this.opts.fullScreen) {
                    this.addFullScreen(this.el);
                }
                if (this.opts.swipe) {
                    this.addSwipe(this.el);
                }
            },
            showCurrent: function (i) {
                // increment or decrement this.counter depending on whether i === 1 or i === -1
                if (i > 0) {
                    this.counter = (this.counter + 1 === this.numItems) ? 0 : this.counter + 1;
                } else {
                    this.counter = (this.counter - 1 < 0) ? this.numItems - 1 : this.counter - 1;
                }

                // remove .show from whichever element currently has it 
                // http://stackoverflow.com/a/16053538/2006057
                [].forEach.call(this.$items, function (el) {
                    el.classList.remove('bss-show');
                });
  
                // add .show to the one item that's supposed to have it
                this.$items[this.counter].classList.add('bss-show');
            },
            injectControls: function (el) {
            // build and inject prev/next controls
                // first create all the new elements
                var spanPrev = document.createElement("span"),
                    spanNext = document.createElement("span"),
                    docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        
                // add classes
                spanPrev.classList.add('bss-prev');
                spanNext.classList.add('bss-next');
        
                // add contents
                spanPrev.innerHTML = '&laquo;';
                spanNext.innerHTML = '&raquo;';
                
                // append elements to fragment, then append fragment to DOM
                docFrag.appendChild(spanPrev);
                docFrag.appendChild(spanNext);
                el.appendChild(docFrag);
            },
            addEventListeners: function (el) {
                var that = this;
                el.querySelector('.bss-next').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
                }, false);
            
                el.querySelector('.bss-prev').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    that.showCurrent(-1); // decrement & show
                }, false);
                
                el.onkeydown = function (e) {
                    e = e || window.event;
                    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
                        that.showCurrent(-1); // decrement & show
                    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
                        that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
                    }
                };
            },
            autoCycle: function (el, speed, pauseOnHover) {
                var that = this,
                    interval = window.setInterval(function () {
                        that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
                    }, speed);
                
                if (pauseOnHover) {
                    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                        interval = clearInterval(interval);
                    }, false);
                    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
                        interval = window.setInterval(function () {
                            that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
                        }, speed);
                    }, false);
                } // end pauseonhover
                
            },
            addFullScreen: function(el){
                var that = this,
                fsControl = document.createElement("span");
                
                fsControl.classList.add('bss-fullscreen');
                el.appendChild(fsControl);
                el.querySelector('.bss-fullscreen').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    that.toggleFullScreen(el);
                }, false);
            },
            addSwipe: function(el){
                var that = this,
                    ht = new Hammer(el);
                ht.on('swiperight', function(e) {
                    that.showCurrent(-1); // decrement & show
                });
                ht.on('swipeleft', function(e) {
                    that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
                });
            },
            toggleFullScreen: function(el){
                // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode
                if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
                    !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement &&   
                    !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
                    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
                      el.requestFullscreen();
                    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
                      el.msRequestFullscreen();
                    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                      el.mozRequestFullScreen();
                    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                      el.webkitRequestFullscreen(el.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                      document.exitFullscreen();
                    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                      document.msExitFullscreen();
                    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
                    }
                }
            } // end toggleFullScreen
            
        }; // end Slideshow object 
        
    // make instances of Slideshow as needed
    [].forEach.call($slideshows, function (el) {
        $slideshow = Object.create(Slideshow);
        $slideshow.init(el, options);
    });
};
var opts = {
    auto : {
        speed : 5000, 
        pauseOnHover : true
    },
    fullScreen : true, 
    swipe : true
};
makeBSS('.demo1', opts);
```

```css
/* body{
  background: ;
  /*overflow: hidden;
} */
.bss-slides{
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  display: block; 
  width:300px;
}
.bss-slides:focus{
 outline: 0;
}
.bss-slides figure{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.bss-slides figure:first-child{
  position: relative;
}
.bss-slides figure img{
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s;
  transition: opacity 1.2s;
  position: relative;
/*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  */
}
.bss-slides .bss-show {
  z-index: 3;
}
.bss-slides .bss-show img{
  opacity: 1;
 /* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;*/
}

.bss-slides figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  bottom: .75em;
  right: .35em;
  padding: .25em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .25);
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s;
  transition: opacity 1.2s;
}
.bss-slides .bss-show figcaption{
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}
.bss-slides figcaption a{
  color: #fff;    
}
.bss-next, .bss-prev{
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .6);
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: -1.2em;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.bss-next:hover, .bss-prev:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}
.bss-next{
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px 15px 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.bss-prev{
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 15px 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
.bss-fullscreen{
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;    
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/arrows-alt_ffffff_64.png); 
  -webkit-background-size: contain; 
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;   
  cursor: pointer;    
  opacity: .3;
} 
.bss-fullscreen:hover{
  opacity: .8;   
}
:-webkit-full-screen .bss-fullscreen{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
:-moz-full-screen .bss-fullscreen{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
:-ms-fullscreen .bss-fullscreen{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
:full-screen .bss-fullscreen{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
:-webkit-full-screen .bss-fullscreen{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
:-moz-full-screen .bss-fullscreen{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
:-ms-fullscreen .bss-fullscreen{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
:fullscreen .bss-fullscreen{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/js/hammer.min.js"></script>
  <div class="bss-slides demo1" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus">
            <figure>
        <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/medium.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Medium" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/thomashawk/14586158819/">Thomas Hawk</a>.</figcaption> 
            </figure>
            <figure>
        <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/colorado.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/stuckincustoms/88370744">Trey Ratcliff</a>.</figcaption> 
            </figure>
            <figure>
        <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/monte-vista.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Early Morning at the Monte Vista Wildlife Refuge, Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/davesoldano/8572429635">Dave Soldano</a>.</figcaption> 
            </figure>
            <figure>
        <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/sunrise.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Sunrise in Eastern Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/35528040@N04/6673031153">Pam Morris</a>.</figcaption> 
            </figure>
            <figure>
        <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/colorado-colors.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"colorado colors" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/cptspock/2857543585">Jasen Miller</a>.</figcaption> 
            </figure>
        </div> <!-- // bss-slides -->
<!-- for swipe support on touch interfaces -->
<div class="num">1 / 5</div>
```

Comment: `indexOf()` не то же самое, что `index()`. `index()` возращает позицию элемента согласно селектору, а `indexOf()` - вообще работает только с массивамию возвращает индекс элемента в массиве. Вам надо написать функцию, которая будет узнавать индекс элемента среди `siblings`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko сделаю если смогу дам ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в функции `showCurrent` есть `this.counter`, который как раз является порядковым номером элемента, единственное, надо к нему прибавлять 1, так как отсчет идет с `0`.

```js
var makeBSS = function(el, options) {
  var $slideshows = document.querySelectorAll(el), // a collection of all of the slideshow
    $slideshow = {},
    Slideshow = {
      init: function(el, options) {
        this.counter = 0; // to keep track of current slide
        this.el = el; // current slideshow container    
        this.$items = el.querySelectorAll('figure'); // a collection of all of the slides, caching for performance
        this.numItems = this.$items.length; // total number of slides         
        options = options || {}; // if options object not passed in, then set to empty object 
        options.auto = options.auto || false; // if options.auto object not passed in, then set to false
        this.opts = {
          auto: (typeof options.auto === "undefined") ? false : options.auto,
          speed: (typeof options.auto.speed === "undefined") ? 1500 : options.auto.speed,
          pauseOnHover: (typeof options.auto.pauseOnHover === "undefined") ? false : options.auto.pauseOnHover,
          fullScreen: (typeof options.fullScreen === "undefined") ? false : options.fullScreen,
          swipe: (typeof options.swipe === "undefined") ? false : options.swipe
        };

        this.$items[0].classList.add('bss-show'); // add show class to first figure 
        //   var $currentIndex = document.querySelector('figure.bss-show').indexOf() + 1; строка ошибки 
        this.injectControls(el);
        this.addEventListeners(el);
        if (this.opts.auto) {
          this.autoCycle(this.el, this.opts.speed, this.opts.pauseOnHover);
        }
        if (this.opts.fullScreen) {
          this.addFullScreen(this.el);
        }
        if (this.opts.swipe) {
          this.addSwipe(this.el);
        }
      },
      showCurrent: function(i) {
        // increment or decrement this.counter depending on whether i === 1 or i === -1
        if (i > 0) {
          this.counter = (this.counter + 1 === this.numItems) ? 0 : this.counter + 1;
        } else {
          this.counter = (this.counter - 1 < 0) ? this.numItems - 1 : this.counter - 1;
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName('num')[0].innerHTML = (this.counter + 1) + ' / ' + this.numItems; //здесь можно осуществлять вывод вашего номера.

        // remove .show from whichever element currently has it 
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/16053538/2006057
        [].forEach.call(this.$items, function(el) {
          el.classList.remove('bss-show');
        });

        // add .show to the one item that's supposed to have it
        this.$items[this.counter].classList.add('bss-show');
      },
      injectControls: function(el) {
        // build and inject prev/next controls
        // first create all the new elements
        var spanPrev = document.createElement("span"),
          spanNext = document.createElement("span"),
          docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        // add classes
        spanPrev.classList.add('bss-prev');
        spanNext.classList.add('bss-next');

        // add contents
        spanPrev.innerHTML = '&laquo;';
        spanNext.innerHTML = '&raquo;';

        // append elements to fragment, then append fragment to DOM
        docFrag.appendChild(spanPrev);
        docFrag.appendChild(spanNext);
        el.appendChild(docFrag);
      },
      addEventListeners: function(el) {
        var that = this;
        el.querySelector('.bss-next').addEventListener('click', function() {
          that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
        }, false);

        el.querySelector('.bss-prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
          that.showCurrent(-1); // decrement & show
        }, false);

        el.onkeydown = function(e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            that.showCurrent(-1); // decrement & show
          } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
          }
        };
      },
      autoCycle: function(el, speed, pauseOnHover) {
        var that = this,
          interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
          }, speed);

        if (pauseOnHover) {
          el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            interval = clearInterval(interval);
          }, false);
          el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            interval = window.setInterval(function() {
              that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
            }, speed);
          }, false);
        } // end pauseonhover

      },
      addFullScreen: function(el) {
        var that = this,
          fsControl = document.createElement("span");

        fsControl.classList.add('bss-fullscreen');
        el.appendChild(fsControl);
        el.querySelector('.bss-fullscreen').addEventListener('click', function() {
          that.toggleFullScreen(el);
        }, false);
      },
      addSwipe: function(el) {
        var that = this,
          ht = new Hammer(el);
        ht.on('swiperight', function(e) {
          that.showCurrent(-1); // decrement & show
        });
        ht.on('swipeleft', function(e) {
          that.showCurrent(1); // increment & show
        });
      },
      toggleFullScreen: function(el) {
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode
        if (!document.fullscreenElement && // alternative standard method
          !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement &&
          !document.msFullscreenElement) { // current working methods
          if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
            el.requestFullscreen();
          } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
            el.msRequestFullscreen();
          } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            el.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            el.webkitRequestFullscreen(el.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
          }
        } else {
          if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
          } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
          } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
          }
        }
      } // end toggleFullScreen

    }; // end Slideshow object 

  // make instances of Slideshow as needed
  [].forEach.call($slideshows, function(el) {
    $slideshow = Object.create(Slideshow);
    $slideshow.init(el, options);
  });
};
var opts = {
  auto: {
    speed: 5000,
    pauseOnHover: true
  },
  fullScreen: true,
  swipe: true
};
makeBSS('.demo1', opts);
```

```css
/* body{
  background: ;
  /*overflow: hidden;
} */

.bss-slides {
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

.bss-slides:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.bss-slides figure {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bss-slides figure:first-child {
  position: relative;
}

.bss-slides figure img {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s;
  transition: opacity 1.2s;
  position: relative;
  /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  */
}

.bss-slides .bss-show {
  z-index: 3;
}

.bss-slides .bss-show img {
  opacity: 1;
  /* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;*/
}

.bss-slides figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  bottom: .75em;
  right: .35em;
  padding: .25em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s;
  transition: opacity 1.2s;
}

.bss-slides .bss-show figcaption {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bss-slides figcaption a {
  color: #fff;
}

.bss-next,
.bss-prev {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: -1.2em;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.bss-next:hover,
.bss-prev:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bss-next {
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px 15px 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.bss-prev {
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 15px 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.bss-fullscreen {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/arrows-alt_ffffff_64.png);
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .3;
}

.bss-fullscreen:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}

:-webkit-full-screen .bss-fullscreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}

:-moz-full-screen .bss-fullscreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

:-ms-fullscreen .bss-fullscreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

:full-screen .bss-fullscreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}

:-webkit-full-screen .bss-fullscreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}

:-moz-full-screen .bss-fullscreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

:-ms-fullscreen .bss-fullscreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
  background-size: contain;
}

:fullscreen .bss-fullscreen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url(https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/img/compress_ffffff_64.png);
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/js/hammer.min.js"></script>
<div class="bss-slides demo1" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/medium.jpg" width="100%" />
    <figcaption>"Medium" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/thomashawk/14586158819/">Thomas Hawk</a>.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/colorado.jpg" width="100%" />
    <figcaption>"Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/stuckincustoms/88370744">Trey Ratcliff</a>.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/monte-vista.jpg" width="100%" />
    <figcaption>"Early Morning at the Monte Vista Wildlife Refuge, Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/davesoldano/8572429635">Dave Soldano</a>.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/sunrise.jpg" width="100%" />
    <figcaption>"Sunrise in Eastern Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/35528040@N04/6673031153">Pam Morris</a>.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/colorado-colors.jpg" width="100%" />
    <figcaption>"colorado colors" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/cptspock/2857543585">Jasen Miller</a>.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
<!-- // bss-slides -->
<!-- for swipe support on touch interfaces -->
<div class="num">1 / 5</div>
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое